# How can I extend a CMFCRibbonPanel in MFC feature Pack

Tags: mfc-feature-pack, cmfcribbonpanel

I want to extend CMFCRibbonPanel - but the constructor is protected (I get the following error: cannot access protected member declared in class 'CMFCRibbonPanel'). The only way to obtain a CMFCRibbonPanel instance is by calling "category->AddPanel", but this way I cannot extend the CMFCRibbonPanel class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A protected constructor is accessible from within the derived class.
My guess is that your derived class CTor is protected, too.
If you make it public, that should work.